# Not obtaining lazy evaluation using sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I would have expected 'a' for this, why 'a:b'?

```
$ echo "a:b:c" | sed -E 's/(.+?):.+/\1/'
a:b
```

Comment: If you ask yourself why you don't get an error or no match at all if the non-greedy `+?` is undefined, it's still a valid ERE with the `?` targeting the `.+` expression, so it's "zero or one occurence of at least one character" – in the end nothing else than `.*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most versions of `sed` don't support perl style regular expressions (the only one I know of that does is "super sed", [ssed](http://sed.sf.net/grabbag/ssed/), and that hasn't been updated since 2005), and don't support the `?` non-greedy modifier.

If you want to use that exact regexp, the easiest solution would be to use `perl`:

```
$ echo "a:b:c" | perl -pe 's/(.+?):.+/$1/'
a
```

Otherwise, modify the regex so that the capture matches any character **except** a colon:

```
$ echo "a:b:c" | sed -E 's/([^:]+):.+/\1/'
a
```